# Want to link to specific sheet in Excel workbook which is stored in SP10 doc library, but usual method not working

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook stored in Sharepoint 2010 document library.  It contains several named sheets.  I want to link to the workbook from a Wiki or List but I want specific sheets to be visible when workbook opened.  I tried using the following command which works fine away from Sharepoint:

path-to-spreadsheet.xls#NamedRange

where #NamedRange is just a range specified on each sheet so they can be identified.  As said, this works fine on the local hard drive but not within SP.  Can it be done?  If so please share the solution.

We are using Sharepoint 2010 and Firefox 3.6.3